# Assigning list to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a data file "list_2_array.dat" as shown below. First, I want to read it and then I want to take control over fourth column elements for further mathematical operations.

```
1 2 3 10  
4 5 6 20  
1 3 5 30  
2 1 4 40  
3 2 3 50
```

I tried following piece of code

```
b_list = []
file=open('/path_to_file/list_2_array.dat', 'r')
m1=[(i.strip()) for i in file]

for j in m1:
    b_list.append(j.replace('\n','').split(' '))

for i in range(5):
    print b_list[i][3]
```

which gives output

```
10  
20  
30  
40  
50
```

I don't want to print the elements, I am interested in first assigning the fourth column elements to a 1-D array so that I can easily process them later. I tried several ways to do this,as one shown below, but did not work

```
   import numpy as np
   for i in range(5):
       arr = array (b_list[i][3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f=open('/path_to_file/list_2_array.dat', 'r')
l = []
for line in f.readlines():
    l.append(int(line.strip().split()[-1]))
array=np.array(l)
```

or more pythonic I guess..:

```
f=open('/path_to_file/list_2_array.dat', 'r')
l = [int(line.strip().split()[-1]) for line in f.readlines()]
array=np.array(l)
```

Comment: Hi Joao, It gives some error!         AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-ec4bae02de8e> in <module>()
      1 file=open('/path_to_file/list_2_array.dat', 'r')
      2 l = []
----> 3 for line in f.readlines():
      4     l.append(line.strip().split()[-1])
      5 

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: @user2964728 ok your file variable is called file and I called my file variable f. Just change one variable name to match the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = """1 2 3 10
4 5 6 20
1 3 5 30
2 1 4 40
3 2 3 50"""
fourth = [int(line.split()[3]) for line in data.split("\n")]
print(fourth)
```

Output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_last_col(file):
last_col = [int(line.split()[-1]) for line in open(file)]
return last_col
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained how it works and how it answers the question.

Comment: @skrrgwasme (it reads a line in as a string, splits it, and changes the the last string in the split array to an int and adds it to the last_col list) for every line in the file

Answer (score 0):

first of all, never assign variable names like str, file, int.
next you were nearly there.

```
b_list = []
c_list = []
file=open('/path_to_file/list_2_array.dat', 'r')
m1=[(i.strip()) for i in file]

for j in m1:
    b_list.append(j.replace('\n','').split(' '))

for i in range(5):
    c_list.append(b_list[i][3])
print c_list
```

I don't really like this solution so I changed @user2994666 his/her solution:

```
file_location = "/path_to_file/list_2_array.dat"
def get_last_col(file_location):
    last_col = [int(line.split()[-1]) for line in open(file_location)]
    return last_col

print get_last_col(file_location)
```

Note that the [-1] solution yields the last column, in your case this gives no problem. In case you have a file with 5 columns and you are still interested in the 4th, you use [3] instead of [-1]